# where to get Fantastico for cPanel

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I am working on a project that requires Fantastico for wordpress installation any body know where can i get that ?

some places say it is not free so anybody can tell its equivalent that is free/opensource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://netenberg.com/fantastico.php

It's 45$ from the developer afaict. C-panel addon here, many hosts offer it with their hosting service. Here's an alternative http://www.softaculous.com/, available as free or premium, but their free does not include wordpress.